# Convert image to div through css

Tags: html, css

Can you help the image below convert to Div or table.
[image]

I have tried but I have stucked only till circle. Div 1, Div 2 till Div 7 I will replace with the Title, So I need those in middle of DIV.I don't need a 3d border, but if you help me with one I will be grateful.

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.cover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip: rect(0 100px 100px 50px);
}

.pie {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    clip: rect(0 50px 100px 0px);
}

#part1-wrapper {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#part1 {
    background-color: #3266FF;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#part2-wrapper {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#part2 {
    background-color: green;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#part3-wrapper {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#part3 {
    background-color: #BF0000;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#part4-wrapper {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}

#part4 {
    background-color: #7030A0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="part1-wrapper" class="cover">
        <div id="part1" class="pie"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="part2-wrapper" class="cover">
        <div id="part2" class="pie"></div>
    </div>
        <div id="part3-wrapper" class="cover">
        <div id="part3" class="pie"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="part4-wrapper" class="cover">
        <div id="part4" class="pie"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For me you didn't try enough, the image show's you'll need `9 divs` but you only got `4` ... In my eyes it's not a something isn't working or how can I solve it question, it's a "can you please do the rest of my work"

Comment: I'm very poor in CSS.Can you please help me to make

Comment: I'd say the css used shows a pretty good attempt, just not the best solution. This kind of stuff is far simpler then it looks, which is exactly what my solution vs the attempt shows. You just have to know the fact CSS very often has sub-properties which do things partially (x/y-overflow, border-left, border-top-left-radius etc)

Answer (score 4):

You can make this significantly simpler by using corner-specific border-radius.

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.pie {
    position: absolute;
    width: 49%;
    height: 49%;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 98px;
}

#part1 {
    background-color: #3266FF;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
}

#part2 {
    background-color: green;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
}

#part3 {
    background-color: #BF0000;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
}

#part4 {
    background-color: #7030A0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
}

#part5 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #333394;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:50px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-25px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="part1" class="pie">part 1</div>
    <div id="part2" class="pie">part 2</div>
    <div id="part3" class="pie">part 3</div>
    <div id="part4" class="pie">part 4</div>
    <div id="part5">part 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the make central image

Comment: @Sree he has done pretty much all of this for you, maybe take this and see if you can expand to get exactly what you need

Comment: Added the middle circle as well, since it works slightly differently. From here you should be able to change this to your needs yourself